# JTable шире jScrollPane

Tags: java, swing

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать чтобы таблица была шире скролпанели, на которой живет, а доступ к невидимой части был через горизонтальный скрол? 
В ScrollPane можно сделать оба скрола и горизонтальный и вертикальный, вот только горизонтальный не активен и скрытая область таблицы отображается при изменении размеров фрейма только.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setAutoResizeMode... закройте вопрос плис